# Verify presence of GUI elements in console application

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

I am currently developing an automated test case which performs actions on a console application (very simple, just clicking buttons and inputting text).

I have been able to successfully click through the application and input data without many problems, which includes identifying elements and things like that.

I have not been able to verify the existence of GUI elements that aren't clickable, ie an image that is loaded into the console application. I have tried looking through the output when using `print_control_identifiers()` for any indication of where data about an image in the window might be stored. I have tried looking at the tree diagram of the windows before and after loading the image in to see if it changes (it does not).

I have also then looked into verifying basic things, like font type or other properties that exist in the VS development platform, without success. To do this I used `handleprops.font` among other things. I have also read through the `handleprops` class and tried to find anything in there that I can use, but none of it is working.

My question is: is there a way to access an image's information that is stored in the window? I am able to identify where it is stored (`picturebox1`) and get information about that window `(handleprops.rectangle)` but cannot get anything about whether the image is there (like a path to image for example). All I can access is 'controllable' items, those that show up in `print_control_identifiers()`

I'm not sure this is possible with `pywinauto` but I have been stuck on this for a while and wondered if there were any suggestions people had.

Thanks

Comment: Changing the image stored in a [static control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-controls) requires sending a message to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - I can successfully load the image in (and in the app that pywinauto is running, I can see the image), I just want to verify, programmatically, that that image is there. What do you mean by 'changing the image'?

Comment: When client code wants to change the image displayed in a static control, it will have to send a message to it. That message can be observed, if needed. Though it sounds like you are trying to verify whether the Common Control code that ships with Windows work as desired. That would be an odd test to run. Some things don't need to be tested.

Comment: Hmm ok, I think that makes sense. Really what I want to be able to do is verify the presence of GUI elements that don't show up in print_control_identifiers(), for example an image. I am able to get the image to display but I'm not able to validate that pythonically. Not sure if this makes sense, but it is the problem I am running into.

Comment: You could capture a screenshot then, and verify that the respective area isn't all solid background color.

Comment: Ok, that is the method that I have seen used online. I wasn't sure if there was a way to look at the elements as you would in a web application, but thank you for the information!